# How finish() work internally

Tags: android

I am building an Android app with a single Activity. The app is supposed to be closed when I click a button which calls the Activity's `finish()` method.

However, the app is still on the running-app list. Shouldn't the app be closed?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I can kill the process completely by running the `killProcess()`, which can be verified by checking the running processes via adb command `adb shell ps`. However, what is confusing is that if I push the multi-task button, my app still shows up as "running".

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Also, I'm still curious why `finish()` won't close a single Activity app completely. Is there a more graceful way to close the app than calling `killProcess()`?

Comment: Do you have a running Service?

Comment: Actually no, just a simple Activity.

Comment: Is the app being closed? Did you check this method was called?

Comment: It was "closed" and the Home screen showed up again. But I guess the finish() might not close the app completely.

Comment: Just curious why some guys down grade the question without giving a reason. If this question is duplicate, please state it is duplicate. If this question is unsuitable here, please tell me why and educate me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal. The Apps in running Apps list are not necessary using CPU, but have a saved state. Android manages this by itself, so don't worry. You shouldn't try to kill it

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove your Activities from the Backstack but all apps are still in this running app list. Honestly I don't know why but there is no process going on so it's OK. This is a constant habit of mine to close all applications manually because I think it drains the power but nowadays I know better